# how to use in memory database in GWT

Tags: gwt, in-memory-database

I want to use in memory database, (NO RDBMS)  in GWT
like when the application starts it retrieve values from the in memory database .
I have no idea how to do this 
If anyone can guide me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for doesn't really make sense, and isn't directly possible.

GWT is a client-side library - it compiles to Javascript and runs like JQuery would do, entirely in the browser. Using RPC or RequestFactory you can talk to existing Java classes on the server using their provided servlets, or you can use any kind of AJAX to get data from the server.

It isn't possible to make connections directly to the server from the browser. Instead, your client should open a connection to the server, and let the server make the connection. If using Java on the server, look for tutorials to connect to a in memory db from Java.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the client storage is a HTML5 thing. Maybe [this project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-client-storage/) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a few options.

SQLLite compiled from C to Javascript
https://github.com/kripken/sql.js

TaffyDB
http://www.taffydb.com/workingwithdata

XBSDB
http://xbsdb.org/demo-js/demo.html